# Error using TADODataset component with MS Access

Tags: delphi, ms-access, tadodataset

I am attempting to replace a InterBase DB with a MS Access DB as a test, I am connect to the MS Access DB using the TADOConnection component successfully; however when I try to connect to a table using the TADODataset, I am able to set the Connection property to the TADOConnection component but when I want to set the CommandText property I receive the following error:

[image: Error message]

The connectionstring is as follows: `Provider=ADsDSOObject;User ID=admin;Encrypt Password=False;Data Source=C:\StudyTime\StudyTime.accdb;Mode=Read;Bind Flags=0;ADSI Flag=-2147483648;`

Can someone please assist me?

Comment: can you show us some code ? And table scheme of the table in interbase and in ms access ?

Comment: And why do you want to move from a client/server database to a desktop database ? Sounds like a big step back to me.

Comment: No code is used for this process of connection, I know what you mean by taking a step back. I wrote this program to help me keep track of my study time and I want to share it with my fellow students who do not have access to InterBase server. Using a MS access DB seems like the logical solution. The table scheme is very simple. There are 2 columns, `Subject_ID` data type `AutoNumber` and `Subject` data type `Text`. The primary key has been set to `Subject_ID`.

Comment: Try to use for test an TADOQuery or TADOTable. 
Same error? Another? No error?

Comment: Can you show us your connectionstring that you use in the connection component ? And what do you see when you click on Details in the errorform ?

Comment: When I use TADOTable the error is:

Comment: [TADOTable - error](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AnKO9VKCanhrkB95Jq2qZ_zU8_a3)

Comment: When I use TADOQuery the error detail is: [TADOQuery - Error](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AnKO9VKCanhrkB6tMkAxJeTdhbXm)

Comment: and how does the connectionstring in the Connection component looks like ?

Comment: `Provider=ADsDSOObject;User ID=admin;Encrypt Password=False;Data Source=C:\StudyTime\StudyTime.accdb;Mode=Read;Bind Flags=0;ADSI Flag=-2147483648;` -When the connection is tested it passes the connection test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a wrong provider: `ADsDSOObject` for ms-access.

Use `Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` or `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;` instead.

e.g.

```
MdbFileName := 'C:\StudyTime\StudyTime.accdb';
ADOConnection1.ConnectionString := Format('Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=%s;', [MdbFileName]);
ADOConnection1.Open;
```